# Firebase rules length validation error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been a while working with firebase and I love it but today I'm working on security rules and I'm getting an error with simulator, my code looks as below:

```
    {
  "rules": {

    "users":{
       "$uid":{

        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",

         ".validate":"newData.child('profile').child('userName').isString()&& newData.val().length < 15"
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

The error appear just when i add the lenght validation. When I do:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "users":{
       "$uid":{

        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",

         ".validate":"newData.child('profile').child('userName').isString()"
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Works fine, any idea why this is happening, I have readed the documentation on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data and many other examples and I just can't find the error. Thank you su much in advice and happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved the correct syntax:

```
    {
  "rules": {

    "users":{
       "$uid":{

        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",

         ".validate":"newData.child('profile').child('userName').isString()&& newData.val().length < 15"
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add validation like this to your field as per this example.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".read" : "$user_id === auth.uid",
        "familyName" : ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 1 && newData.val().length < 100",
        "givenName" : ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 1 && newData.val().length < 100",
        "age" : ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() > 13 && newData.val() < 110",
        "email": {
          // an email is only allowed in the profile if it matches
          // the auth token's email account (for Google or password auth)
          ".validate": "newData.val() === auth.email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```